# Render methods should be a pure function of props and state error while updating state

Tags: reactjs

```
class App extends React.Component{
     render(){
         const{showError, errorMsg} = this.props;
         return(
             <div>
                 {showError && <div>{errorMsg}</div>}
             </div>
         )
    }
}
```

I want to display errorMsg only when showError is true. I keep getting this error

```
Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; triggering nested component updates from render is not allowed. If necessary, trigger nested updates in componentDidUpdate
```

Comment: Where did you defined the showError and errorMsg, could you provide that component?

Comment: I tried the component you provided in a sandbox and found no errors.